# ASP.NET MVC: Access Data in Controller from another controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Please feel free to edit the title if it is misleading, since I am not sure if that's the correct way to ask.

I am new to ASP.NET MVC I am running into a seemly easy problem and having a hard time doing it.

**What I am trying to do:** I have two sets of scaffolds: View A, Controller A, Model B. and View B, Controller B, Model B.

Controller A looks like this:

```
public ActionResult LogIn(FormCollection formValues)
{
    ModelA Model = new ModelA();
    Model.EmailAddress = formValues["EmailAddress"];
}
```

I want to pass this `formValues["EmailAddress"]` from controller A to controller B.

In controller B, I have:

```
public ActionResult Initiate(FormCollection formValues, string phone, string method)
{
    var ModelB = new ModelB();
    var ModelA = new ModelA(); ---> This is null.
    ModelB.Email = ModelA.EmailAddress --> This is null.
    var userId = ModelB.dosomething(ModelB.Email, phone, method);
}
```

Is there away of doing that?

Comment: You can use `Session["EmailAddress"] = ModelA.EmailAddress`;

Comment: @chakeda I am assuming that the session  is similar to TempData. It seems like it is a one-off thing. Is there a natural way that fits the work flor or MVC?

Comment: How is one controller calling the other? By using Redirect? Action?

Comment: @D.R. Currently, they are completely seperated. However, in the future, View B is right after View A(navigated by buttons). I havn't figure out a way to do that either sadly, was going to to that after I finished this. Now you mentioned it, it sounds like it may be a better idea to connect two views first to creat a work flow.

Comment: @aDev Having data persist between requests from A to B is what Sessions are for - I would argue that posting data between different controllers is not the intended flow of MVC. You could have A and B share functions (`dosomething()`), or call `dosomething()` in `Login()`.

Comment: Seeing your most recent comment, a ViewModel + Controller + View that interfaces both Model A and Model B would be elegant too!

Comment: You can use TempData until assign it, then you tempdata will have gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the logic of ModelA and ModelB are going to be intertwined, I would recommend creating a new ViewModel, View, and Controller:

**ModelAB**

```
public class AB {
    public ModelA ModelA { get; set; }
    public ModelB ModelB { get; set; }
}
```

**ModelABController**

```
public ActionResult LogInAndInitiate(FormCollection formValues, string phone, string method)
{
    var ModelB = new ModelB();
    var ModelA = new ModelA(); // passed in, so its not null!
    ModelA.EmailAddress = formValues["EmailAddress"];

    ModelB.Email = ModelA.EmailAddress // passed in too!
    var userId = ModelB.dosomething(ModelB.Email, phone, method);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Save the Model in TempData in Controller A like this

```
ModelA Model = new ModelA();
Model.EmailAddress = formValues["EmailAddress"];
TempData["ModelA"]=Model;
```

and Then You can Acces it in Controller B like this

```
ModelA modelA= TempData["ModelA"] as ModelA;
```

However TempData has very short life and can not be used in subsequent requests
to keep the TempData persistant for subsequent request you can use

```
TempData.Keep();
```

Comment: You should explain that TempData values have  a very short lifetime

Comment: is this the only way in ASP.MVC? seems kind of hacky. Is there an approach that betters fits the MVC flow?

Answer (score 1):

If the controller actions are completely unrelated (i.e., they do not call each other) you have two options:

1) Render the data to the client into a form and let the data be re-posted on the next request. This is of course only suitable for small amounts of data AND if you are sure it is neither sensitive nor a problem if the user tampers with the data.

2) Use sessions. This is what sessions are for, i.e., shopping cart contents, etc. You can opt to save this data in a database or have it in-memory in a session object only.

I wouldn't recommend using TempData for this, the idea behind TempData is to contain data which is useful for the very next request only. Think validation messages and that kind of data.